# SQL drawing twice on the same variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm an SQL newbie, I've spent quite a bit of time on this but can't crack it.

My database has individuals `PersonID` as the primary key.

One table references `Work_Units`.

`Work_Units` can be either that person's usual work unit, or their secondary work unit - the two are unrelated.

I want to show both a person's usual and secondary work units in a SQL statement, which means searching for the same variable `Work_Unit`, but referenced from two different tables.

I have been told I need to use a subquery, but I can't get it to work - does the subquery need to go in the `SELECT` clause, the `FROM` clause of the `WHERE` clause?

TIA, Peter

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. A database tag may also be useful: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64519057/edit) to add that important piece of information. Along with your sample data, please also show the result that you expect.

Comment: The database table where PersonID is the primary field I believe that is Person table. The question is in that table is there any field that holds the ID for Primary Work_Unit and another field that holds the ID for Secondary Work_Unit?

Comment: This is a big health system database - one table holds person identifiers, PersonID code and Primary Work Unit code, that links to another table that holds Work_Unit names. Another table holds Secondary Work Unit codes and PersonID code. I'm simplfying a bit, but that gives the general picture.

Comment: In relational databases we have *tables* with *columns*. A database doesn't have a primary key, a table does. Is the "variable" in your question a value in a column?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are multiple ways to do it. It would help if you'd edit your question and include the layout of the tables involved, but I'll give it a shot:

You can either put the subquery into the SELECT clause if you *know* that the subquery will only return a single row:

```
SELECT i.NAME,
       (SELECT w.WORK_UNIT
          FROM WORK_UNITS w
          WHERE w.PERSONID = i.PERSONID AND
                w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY') AS PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT,
       (SELECT w.WORK_UNIT
          FROM WORK_UNITS w
          WHERE w.PERSONID = i.PERSONID AND
                w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'SECONDARY') AS SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
  FROM INDIVIDUALS i
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99c7c32034e1f4a8503e91b7d57590b1)

or if the subqueries can return more than one row you can join them into the main query:

```
SELECT i.NAME,
       pwu.PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT,
       swu.SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
  FROM INDIVIDUALS i
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY') pwu
    ON pwu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'SECONDARY') swu
    ON swu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=512531822bfd4bddbab4832746957e86)

or if you really want to you can put the secondary work units together into a comma-separated list:

```
SELECT i.NAME,
       pwu.PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT,
       LISTAGG(swu.SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pwu.PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT) AS SECONDARY_WORK_UNITS
  FROM INDIVIDUALS i
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY') pwu
    ON pwu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'SECONDARY') swu
    ON swu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
  GROUP BY i.NAME, pwu.PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a31327445232accc06004c39dd0c3849)

Comment: Thanks Bob, sorry I couldn't provide more detail, I'm at home and I only have access to the db at work. I'll give that a shot tomorrow and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

A variant on the second option given by @Bob Jarvis:

In stead of doing:

```
SELECT i.NAME,
       pwu.PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT,
       swu.SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
  FROM INDIVIDUALS i
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY') pwu
    ON pwu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT w.PERSONID,
                     w.WORK_UNIT AS SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
                FROM WORK_UNITS w
                WHERE w.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'SECONDARY') swu
    ON swu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID
```

may i suggest doing:

```
SELECT i.NAME,
       pwu.WORK_UNIT as PRIMARY_WORK_UNIT,
       swu.WORK_UNIT as SECONDARY_WORK_UNIT
  FROM INDIVIDUALS i
 INNER JOIN WORK_UNITS pwu 
    ON pwu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID AND pwu.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY'
 INNER JOIN WORK_UNITS swu 
    ON swu.PERSONID = i.PERSONID and swu.WORK_UNIT_TYPE = 'SECONDARY'
```

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer OP's question "...does the subquery need to go in the SELECT clause, the FROM clause of the WHERE clause?".

Comment: Or you could read it as "you do not need a subquery at all". But that is just my opinion... 